# Regex for self hosted renovate bot to fetch linuxserver.io stable images

Tags: regex, versioning, regex-negation, renovate

I've setup the renovate selfhosted bot. Since linuxserver.io has different schemas of creating docker tags, i'll switched to regex.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:base",
    "docker:enableMajor"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "packagePatterns": ["^ghcr.io\\/linuxserver\\/"],
      "versionScheme": "regex:MYFANCYREGEX"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I need help getting the regex up and running.
I created a regex 101 with unittest and example - [here](https://regex101.com/r/KQZykk/1)

```
100.200.300
100.200.300.7068-ls170
v100.200.300-ls213
version-100.200.300
version-100.200.300-ls180
version-100.200.300.11111
100.200.300.7068-ls170
nigthly-100.200.300  -> not stable, no match
nightly-100.200.300.3604-ls587  -> not stable, no match
100.200.300-development -> not stable, no match
100.200.300-develop -> not stable, no match
100.200.300-nigthly -> not stable, no match
```

I'm somehow not able to exclude matches containing something -> (?! or ^)

How should I change the regex to only get stable builds and the image updates (ls/buildnumbers)

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to match/not match, and what the rules are for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with this regex (using the **x** flag for readability):

```
/^

# Build information should not contain dev and nightly stuff:
(?!.*(nig(ht|th)ly|develop|development))

# Optional compatibility prefix "version-" or "v":
(?<compatibility>[a-z]*-|v)?

# Major, minor and patch numbers:
(?<major>\d+)\.(?<minor>\d+)\.(?<patch>\d+)

# Capture the optional build information:
(?:
  [\.-]?
  (?<build>.*)
)?

$/gmx
```

Updated your regex101 case study here: https://regex101.com/r/KQZykk/4

If you cannot use the **x** flag then use the uncommented version that
I added here: https://regex101.com/r/KQZykk/5

PS: To pass from commented to uncommented regex, I created a little
tool that you can access here: https://codepen.io/patacra/pen/wvQBxjq

Comment: I really like the shorter and cleaner form! Thanks

Comment: You mean version 4 instead of version 2? Yes, it's easier like that!

Comment: Found the root cause, it looks like RE2 doens't support negatives

Comment: In this case, without the negative lookahead: https://regex101.com/r/KQZykk/7